# How to implement MDC (Material Design Component) tooltips?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mdc-components

I have been setting up a simple web guide without using any framework, by just using separate [Material Design Components](https://material.io/components?platform=web). Many of these I had no issues with (I have successfully implemented buttons with ripple effects, cards, tabs...) but I can not get tooltips to work.
Following the [documentation](https://material.io/components/tooltips/web#using-tooltips), I have tried many things to make them appear, but they do not show.

They are included in my CSS:

```css
@use "@material/tooltip/styles";
```

Instanciated in my JS:

```js
import {MDCTooltip} from '@material/tooltip';
const tooltip = new MDCTooltip(document.querySelector('.mdc-tooltip'));
```

And implemented in my HTML as per the example given, first the tooltip is declared in the body:

```html
<div id="tooltip-1" class="mdc-tooltip" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="mdc-tooltip__surface mdc-tooltip__surface-animation">
    TestyMcTest
  </div>
</div>
```

...and then the tooltip is attached to another element in the same body:

```html
<div aria-describedby="tooltip-1" class="mdc-card in-card-margins">
  <div>The status of these data updates can be observed in the blabla</div>
</div>
```

The tooltip div is made invisible (which is expected behaviour), however, nothing shows up when mousing over the linked object (in this instance a card, but I tried with multiple types of containers and I could not get anything to work).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try to put it into a sandbox example.

Comment: @Allexio, did you ever figure this out?